# Nikon Z6 USB charging

Tags: nikon, battery, usb, charger

To charge the battery of the Z6 Nikon states in its user manual that the [EH-7P AC charger](https://www.nikon.co.uk/en_GB/product/accessories/mirrorless/mirrorless-power/ac-adaptors/ac-adapter-eh-7p) is needed.

However when I plug the camera into my computer (MacBook) and the camera is off, the orange LED on the side that indicates the charging state turns on.

So I was wondering what would happen if I used my phone charger (5V 2A) to charge the battery of the camera. Would it work?

P.S.
It works with my phone charger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will *probably* charge the battery, but likely at a slower rate than Nikon's EH-7P USB-C battery charger.

According to a Nikon employee's response to the question titled "USB-C power specifications" at [Nikon's product forum for the EH-7P](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/power-adapters/eh-7p-charging-ac-adapter.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-Forum) (Nikon doesn't create direct permalinks for questions asked at its product forums), the EH-7P has a maximum rated output of 3A at 5V, which is 50% more power output than your phone's charger. Your Z6's battery will probably take about 50% longer to charge when using your phone's charger.